# Inside a loop, the non-loop variable did not get the array from the loop variables in Markdown, Pandoc and YAML

Tags: html, for-loop, yaml, markdown, pandoc

Observe well the last variable `mais`, which will get the array from the variable `icones`:

- YAML in a Markdown file:

```
---

gnome: 'gnome'

icones:
  - {nome: actions}
  - {nome: apps}
  - {nome: devices}
  - {nome: mimetypes}
  - {nome: places}
  - {nome: status}

mais:
  - {url: 'filename.com/$icones.nome$/logo=$gnome$'}

---
```

- In another Markdown file:

```
$for(icones)$
  <img alt="$icones.nome$"   name="$icones.nome$"   src="https://$mais.url$"/>
$endfor$
```

The item will get successfully all the variables, but the variable `$mais.url$` will not get the array variables.

Here is the result:

```
<img alt="actions"   name="actions"   src="https://"/>
<img alt="apps"   name="apps"   src="https://"/>
<img alt="devices"   name="devices"   src="https://"/>
<img alt="mimetypes"   name="mimetypes"   src="https://"/>
<img alt="places"   name="places"   src="https://"/>
<img alt="status"   name="status"   src="https://"/>
```

It should be like:

```
<img alt="actions"   name="actions"   src="https://filename.com/actions/logo=gnome"/>
<img alt="apps"      name="apps"      src="https://filename.com/apps/logo=gnome"/>
<img alt="devices"   name="devices"   src="https://filename.com/devices/logo=gnome"/>
<img alt="mimetypes" name="mimetypes" src="https://filename.com/mimetypes/logo=gnome"/>
<img alt="places"    name="places"    src="https://filename.com/places/logo=gnome"/>
<img alt="status"    name="status"    src="https://filename.com/status/logo=gnome"/>
```

Comment: I suppose those are pandoc template files, or..? how do you call pandoc? what version?

Comment: ah, shouldn't it be `$mais.first.url$` instead of `$mais.url$`

Comment: @mb21, yes, it is correct, my Pandoc version on Arch Linux is 2.8. I run the command `pandoc variables.md --template readme-dev.md -o readme-test.md`.

Comment: Do I need to add `first` in YAML code, @mb21?

Comment: yes, like: `<img alt="$icones.nome$"   name="$icones.nome$"   src="https://$mais.first.url$"/>`

Comment: see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$icones$` is only referring to a single item in `icones:` *inside the for loop*, i.e. not inside the value of `mais:`. Likewise, the for loop iterates over `$icones$`, so `$mais$` does not refer to a single value of the `mais:` sequence.

You could do something like this:

```
mais:
  - {url: {front: "filename.com/", back: "/logo=$gnome$"}}
```

And then:

```html
$for(icones)$
  <img alt="$icones.nome$"   name="$icones.nome$"   src="https://$mais.first.url.front$$icones.nome$$mais.first.url.back$"/>
$endfor$
```